# OAuth2 client app with Sping Boot 3.0.5 and Retrofit

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to access resources from a remote OAuth2 Resource server using a client OAuth2 spring boot application that uses Retrofit for calling the server ? I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.5 and I'm not able to get the access token from the OAuth Authorization Server and use it with retrofit. It looks like the documentation is missing with the last versions of Sporing boot. Any hint ? I need to get the access token from the Authorization Server and then get some resources from a OAuth2 Resource  Server. It looks like I cannot find a working example for Spring boot 2.0.5. With Postman is ok, I mean, I can get the access token and use it to call the endpoint but programmatically using Retrofit looks impossible.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Retrofit website](https://A%20type-safe%20HTTP%20client%20for%20Android%20and%20Java) header:

> A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java

It is rather clear that, out of the box, you should not expect any particular integration with Spring...

What you should do start with is configuring your Spring application as an [OAuth2 client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html) (with Boot it's a matter of an import and a few properties).

Then either:

- retrieve authorized client with `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` and hand write Retrofit configuration with it (you'll find tokens for a specific client registration there)
- use a REST client that better integrates with boot than Retrofit like Spring's reactive [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client) or Spring Cloud [`@FeignClient`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) (the later being declarative like Retrofit)

Comment: RETROFIT is not the problem. The problem is to create a working OAuth2 client application able to connect to a custom (mine) OAuth3 Authorization Server and get the token. With Post Man (Insomnia it works), I need to clone the same behavior with Spring Boot (same behavior of Postman and Insomnia)

Comment: What do you think I wrote about? An application fetching tokens from an authorization server to later authorize its requests to resource servers is a client. Both Postman and Insomnia are OAuth2 clients already.

Comment: Hi ch4mp, thank you for your help. I got what you ment. But have you a link to some documentation that explain how to achieve that in Spring Boot 3.0.5 ? That's my problem right now, because I didn't find it.